# Cargo won't install from crates.io

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

When trying to install any crate that comes from crates.io, I get this error.

```
PS D:\ThisGuy\Rust> cargo install adler
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to download from `https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/adler/1.0.2/download`

Caused by:
  [60] SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.)
```

Digging into it I found that the school's DNS server actually blocks any .io website and won't allow me to work with it.
[Securely uses a DNS server to block disallowed websites. This actually is causing me more pain than you could imagine. Reddit, Unity, Crates, they're all blocked :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG2RI.png) 
Since tech tickets take time to process, I was wondering if there are any alternative ways to work around this? Maybe a cargo command to install from a file instead of from a URL, or perhaps the ability to provide alternative URL's?
Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you can get the source, you can `cargo install` locally using `--path`. Is that what you need?

Comment: so would that just be cargo install adler --path <Insert Path>? Because if so then I think so. I just need to know how to tell cargo to install it from somewhere other than crates.io

Comment: Wait a minute, [adler](https://github.com/jonas-schievink/adler/tree/master) doesn't have a binary crate so there's nothing to `cargo install`. Do you just mean you want to use it as a dependency?

Comment: I'm trying to install iced and serde as dependencies, but one of them uses adler as a dependency so that's kinda what I'm trying to do. Still new, forgot to clarify.

Comment: That's ok, but you don't use `cargo install` for dependencies, you use `cargo add` or manually put it in your `Cargo.toml` `[dependencies]`. Anyway, not being able to use crates.io at all is a bit of a pain: you can use a git repository as a direct dependency but those will end up using crates.io for secondary dependencies. The better solution would be to use a different registry altogether, but I don't know a public crates.io mirror.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to patch every subdependency to use git as well (and hope they're hosted on an allowed domain). Another solution is to use a different machine to [vendor](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-vendor.html) the dependencies, and then copy them over.

Comment: Consider asking your school administration to make an exception to the filter. If securely is purely a DNS filter, you can switch DNS servers. Failing that, you can find a proxy and [configure cargo to use it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#httpproxy), or use a VPN service.

Comment: You can use a tool to create a local mirror like [panamax](https://github.com/panamax-rs/panamax) and use that instead of `crates.io`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I got my CS teacher to send in a ticket, but whether it gets fulfilled is out of my hands at this point. Also, switching DNS servers is a no-go because the computers have the connections properties section locked down. Unsure if a VPN would install either since the computers have deep-freeze and program files are admin-locked. If there is one that needs no install in program files though let me know.

Comment: @Thisguy If you're using a lab computer - and it sounds like it if they have deep freeze on it - you likely don't have permission to install software on it or edit its settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some network proxies used in schools tend to interfere with package registries, git hosting services, and other important sites. I've experienced this with sites that have "suspicious" keywords in the name (*hacking*withswift.com, *hacker*rank.com) as well as a wide range of seemingly completely random domains (even GitHub, unfortunately). This makes it frustrating or impossible to use many developer tools you'd normally take for granted; even cloning a git repo can be impossible to do correctly.

To fix the problem, you may need to use your own local proxy with a tool like [WARP](https://1.1.1.1/).